# Proper package for consuming data from RabbitMQ and then streaming to Dask

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, spark-streaming, dask-distributed

I am using Dask for parallel processing and RabbitMQ as a message queue. As my data is streaming data, I need a package that can stream the data to Dask.
I found "Streamz", but I don't know how to consume data using Streamz.
Can anyone suggest a proper package for that?
How can I consume data using that package and then stream to Dask?

Comment: Post the code you are working with currently. What data is flowing so far, and what part of it would a Streamz consumer be interested in?

Comment: @J_H, sorry, I can't share the data, as this is from my work. It's some Network data from the server. All I need to do is to queue them using RabbitMQ and then stream them to Dask. Dask will take the data and process them parallelly using some Machine Learning Techniques.

Comment: You have not yet read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- it explains how to post some dummy data, such as from `range( ... )` or from `random()`, to illustrate how your program has assembled the plumbing, connecting _this_ to _that_, even if folks who might consider spending time to answer your question are unable to see the details of _what_ data is flowing through the connected pipes.